# Is there a more idiomatic way to say "to begin again"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, idiom

*Incipere iterum* seems like a very literal way to say "to begin again". Is there a more idiomatic way to say this? For additional context, when I think of this phrase, I think of something cyclic, where it would begin again and again.

Comment: I feel like there should be some good prefixed verb for this, but _recipere_ doesn't seem to have had that meaning, and _coepi_ doesn't generally take prefixes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with *incipere iterum*, you could also say:

- **denuo incipere**
- **rursus incipere**

There are also a number of single verbs encapsulating that meaning:

- **repetere**, generally “repeat” etc.
- **renovare**, literally “renew, restore,” also “repeat your previous words.” Like you can “renew” your efforts in English, it can also be used that way in Latin; e.g. *hi nostros disiectos adorti proelium renovarunt* (Caesar, [De bello Gallico 3,20](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0002%3Abook%3D3%3Achapter%3D18%3Asection%3D4) – not sure why Perseus thinks it's 18).
- **integrare**, beginning again “from scratch, from the start”
- **instaurare**, this word seems to be popular with festivities of various sorts (*sacrificium, sacra, ludos*), but can also be used more generally, e.g. *cum in Cn. Dolabellam suum scelus illud pristinum renovavit et instauravit* (Cicero, [In Verrem 1,4](https://www.thelatinlibrary.com/cicero/ver1.shtml)).

Comment: Out of curiosity, if I said something like _Incipere iterum iterumque_, would it mean _begin again and again_ and not read strangely?

Comment: One more thought: if using the adverb twice with -que makes sense, what about changing the word order to _Iterum Incipere Iterumque_ (or even _Rursus Incipere Rursusque_)?

Comment: @Adam *iterum iterumque, iterum atque iterum, iterumque iterumque* are all attested with the meaning "again and again, repeatedly" according to L&S and Georges. For *rursus* this does not appear to be the case.

Comment: Ok, thank you! I need to make it a habit to check sources more.

Comment: @Adam Another great resource is [Döderlein’s Hand-book of Latin Synonymes](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=do270) by the way ;-)

Comment: @Adam Incidentally, another way to say “again and again” would be simply *identidem*, which also happens to be a pretty cool sounding word in my opinion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127645/discussion-between-adam-and-sebastian-koppehel).