# "And I am done with my graceless heart..."

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check, song-lyrics

I've come up with the following translation for the Florence + The Machine lyric "And I am done with my graceless heart, so tonight I'm going to cut it out and then restart":

> Et corde dedecoro defungor, ita hac nocte exsecabo et deinde renascar

Questions:

1. Is this a technically correct translation?
2. Does it sound like natural Latin?
3. Is the choice of "exsecabo" for "I will cut out" optimal?  There were a lot of choices.
4. Finally, advice on making the result more metrically pleasing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

A few notes:

- *Exsecare* seems a good fit. *Excidere* would also be an option.
- *Ita* is not correct (it answers to *quomodo*), it should be *itaque* (or *quare* for example, there are many possibilities).
- I also think it is uncommon to combine *et* with *deinde* – at least classically – so it seems more idiomatic to me to strike the *et*. You could also simply say *tum*. In fact, you can even say *tum deinde*.
- You probably know what you're doing with *renascar*, but we did have a [question about “beginning again”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/16419) recently, so I thought I'd throw *de integro incipere* in the ring.
- I like how you avoided translating “my” and “it,” that feels quite “natural” to me (quamvis imperitus sim Latinitatis).
- I cannot help you with the metre.

Regarding “graceless,” an interesting discussion has developed in the comments. The English word is ambiguous; it has an older, religiously coloured meaning “lacking in divine grace, immoral” (see [Merriam-Webster's entry here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/graceless)), which probably also underlies [Smith & Hall's suggestions](https://www.latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries?t=sh11324) *improbus, nequam*), and it can also refer to clumsy or unrefined conduct (which we might render as *inelegans* or *illepidus*).

We cannot tell for sure what is the intended meaning, and besides it may be intentionally ambiguous. (This is poetry, where words are more often than in prose not chosen for their meaning alone, but also for connotations, associations, or just how they sound.) A possibility would be to say *corde inani gratiae*, which is quite literal.

In summary I would say:

> Et corde improbo defungor, itaque hac nocte exsecabo, tum de integro incipiam.

Comment: *improbus* also means "disgraceful" or even "dishonest". I think the range of meaning for it is too large to use for "graceless" (as in lacking grace, inelegant). Assuming she doesn't mean "lacking *mercy*", I would have went with something like *inelegans* or perhaps even *haud lepidus* (as *inlepidus* is rare), or perhaps a better word but along those lines. Thoughts?

Comment: @cmw That depends on your interpretation of the lyrics. I do not find it compelling that a heart should be thought "inelegant" or, if so, be cut out on that count. Rather I suspect the author had the more traditional, religious meaning of "graceless" in mind, which Merriam-Webster gives as "immoral, unregenerate," and which probably also underlies Smith & Hall's translation as "improbus, nequam."

Comment: I hadn't even considered the older religious meaning. I think you might be right. It's the opposite then of *plena gratiae*?

Comment: @cmw Indeed, perhaps one could say *corde inani gratiae*.

Comment: *Ingratus* might also be an option to consider, though I'm also not sure exactly what "graceless" means here.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Clunkiness aside, I think it works better than *improbus*. Even having read the lyrics again (which I never before precisely knew, though I've listened to the song a dozen times), I'm not 100% sold she means it's wicked. For what it's worth, [genius](https://genius.com/13583147) also went with "lacking charm." Ultimately we'd have to ask Florence, but I think *inani gratiae* at least keeps the same word whence we got *graceless*.

Comment: @TKR I think that actually works best so far, since it has the negative connotation that Sebastian was going for and is etymologically equivalent to *graceless*. +1.